# Traducir React JS sin Node

Tags: reactjs

La pregunta es simple, hay alguna forma de realizar la traducción de mi sitio a otro idioma (pasar del Español al Portugués por ejemplo) como se podría hacer con [esta librería](https://github.com/martinandert/react-translate-component) pero sin necesidad de instalar Node y migrar toda la App hecha al mismo?

En caso de que no se pueda, ¿que alternativas me quedan?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Realizar que? La traducción o evitar Node?

Comment: quieres traducir un codigo ya escrito?

Comment: Quiero traducir a otro idioma (como portugués) el HTML generado por React, como hace la librería que cité en la pregunta. El código React ya lo tengo terminado, usando Symfony y Babel in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final declaré un diccionario en javascript que forma parte del state con las traducciones:

```
var lenguajeENG = {
    "hola": "hello",
    ...
}
```

Por default viene vacío:

```
this.state = {
    idioma: {}
}
```

Y así con cada idioma que necesito. Después de eso, tengo tengo una función `trad()`:

```
/*
 * Traduce al idioma seteado la palabra pasada por parametro
 */
trad(palabra) {
    if (this.state.idioma[palabra] !== undefined) 
        return this.state.idioma[palabra];

    return palabra;
}
```

Cada vez que quiero cambiar el lenguaje lo único que hago es cambiar el lenguage cambio el state de la variable `idioma`:

```
/*
 * Cambia el diccionario de idioma
 */
seleccionarIdioma(idioma = 'esp') {
    let proximoIdioma;
    switch(idioma) {
        case 'eng': // Ingles
            proximoIdioma = lenguajeENG;
            break;
        default:
            idioma = 'esp'
            proximoIdioma = []; // Diccionario vacio
            break;
    }
    this.setState({ idioma: proximoIdioma });
    this.idiomaSeleccionado = idioma;
};
```